# JUnit expects IOException when IOE is thrown, marks test as failed

Tags: java, junit, tdd, ioexception

I've got a few test methods that aren't behaving as I expect them to be. In these scenarios, I'm writing logging messages to a text file.

Both methods are about closing the output link to the file and attempting to write to it. Obviously this means I expect an `IOException` which is also reflected in my code.

These are the two test methods I'm talking about

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void writeToClosedConnection() throws IOException {
    LogHandler.getInstance().createNewChatlog("Jack");
    LogHandler.getInstance().stopLogging(); // Closes the bufferedWriter
    LogHandler.getInstance().writeToChatLog(new Message("Jim", "CAN'T WORK"));
}

@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void closeStream() throws IOException {
    log = new ChatLog(new GregorianCalendar(), "STANDARDTESTLOG", directory);
    log.closeLogFile(); // Closes the bufferedWriter
    log.addMessage(new Message("Jim", "CAN'T WORK"));
}
```

Both methods to write messages belong in the same route. `writeToChatLog` invokes `addMessage`, which will in turn call on the `writeToLogFile` method.

This last method is defined as

```
protected void writeToLogFile(String message) {
    try {
        if (logging) {
            bWriter.write(message);
            bWriter.newLine();
            bWriter.flush();
        } else {
            throw new ForbiddenActionException("Logging is disabled");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        OutputUtil.showErrorMessage("Couldn't write to logfile", "IO error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The issue at hand is that even though IO errors are thrown (twice this:)

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at io.Log.writeToLogFile(Log.java:41)
    at io.ChatLog.addMessage(ChatLog.java:16)
    at tests.ChatLogTest.closeStream(ChatLogTest.java:76)
```

and the popup message (`Couldn't write to logfile`) is shown, I still get an assertionError (`java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.io.IOException`).

JUnit is version 4.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Short version: If you catch it inside the test runner can't catch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never really throw `IOException`. Inside `writeToLogFile` you catch it, log it and do nothing else. From you outside world perspective nothing wrong happened:

```
protected void writeToLogFile(String message) {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You see, even if `IOException` was thrown, it's suppressed. Thus it never *escapes* out of `writeToClosedConnection()` method so JUnit can't see it. And it fails the test. A quick solution would be to propagate the exception, which unfortunately requires modifying your signature:

```
protected void writeToLogFile(String message) throws IOException {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //...
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers are clear, thanks a lot! Is there a commonly accepted practice to handle the Exception at the "lowest" level or higher up? Right now the hierarchy goes like this: GUI -> LogHandler -> Log (abstract) -> ChatLog. Should I handle the exception in my LogHandler or the ChatLog?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: you should handle the exception where you *can*. If you can't do anything useful with the exception, just let it propagate up. If you think `ChatLog` can solve the problem somehow, let it do it. Otherwise just give up and propagate to `LogHandler`. `LogHandler` can try to solve the problem or even propagate further, so that GUI can try handling it.

Comment: Honestly I feel like `Log` would be the best place considering that's where the actual writing is done and all other classes simply pass this method on. However, this would also mean these tests won't work. If I'd rethrow the `Exception` higher up the ranking, a lot of methods would suddenly require a different signature and the `writeToLogFile` method is being called in several different methods. Just to satisfy the test, I'd have to try-catch 5 times instead of once. I'm more inclined to remove the tests all together, how is this looked upon?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: if you simply handle that exception inside `Log` then no code calling it will ever know that logging failed. It depends on your requirements whether this is what you want or not. From the testing perspective - you can either wrap `IOException` into unchecked exception so it's *invisible* and can bubble upple or test your logging failure in a different way. Since you cannot distinguish between successful and failed call to `Log` from outside, you have to look for some side effects.

Answer (score 4):

`writeToLogFile()` doesn't throw an IOException. If it did, it would have to be declared as

```
protected void writeToLogFile(String message) throws IOException {
```

You're explicitely *catching* any IOException that could be thrown from the instructions in `writeToLogFile()`. Catching an exception is precisely used to avoid the exception to be thrown.

Don't catch IOException, and declare the IOException in the method declaration, and the test will pass:

```
protected void writeToLogFile(String message) throws IOException {
    if (logging) {
        bWriter.write(message);
        bWriter.newLine();
        bWriter.flush();
    } else {
        throw new ForbiddenActionException("Logging is disabled");
    }
}
```